# Issue with form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using form_tag in my create.html.erb file. Under this form_tag there is a button. Now I wish that after clicking the button the page will be refreshed only ,I dont want to redirect anywhere . So what should I write in my form tag as path?

For session controller my view/sessions/create.html.erb file is:

```
<h4>Database contents here:</h4>

<table>                         
  <tr>  
    <th>ID</th>                        
    <th>AGE</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
  </tr>
  <% @data.each do |data| %>       
    <tr>
      <td><%= data.id %></td>  
      <td><%= data.age %></td>  
      <td><%= data.name %></td> 
    </tr>
  <% end %>                        
</table> 

<div>
  <%= form_tag :method => :get do %>
    <%= button_tag type: 'submit'  do %>
      <%= content_tag :div do%>
        <h4>View Data </h4><h4><%= @num %></h4>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And my contollers/sessions_controller file is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def index
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    @data=Information.all
    @num=Information.count()
    @tym=Time.now.getutc
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      #redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"

      #this part is for showing the content of the information table


      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml { render xml: @data }
      end
    else
     flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
     render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Comment: use redirect_to :back in the controller action which is hit by the form.

Comment: sorry acn not get it...Actually new in rails. Can you tell me where to write this?

Comment: When you click on the button does it hit any action in the controller ?

Comment: Yes,,,it should show the content of the database..

Comment: If it hits a controller action then redirect_to :back in the controller action should work

Comment: you can use ajax , remote:true in your view & create a js file which will render the output

Comment: I have provided my controller code but I dont know where to specify that line which you are talking about. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to refresh your page then you do not need to do a form_tag, why not you redirect back to that page on button click

```
<%= button_to "Refresh", sessions_path, :method => :get %>
```